# Error:TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT when Using Stacking ensemble for classification model

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

I want to build classification model using the stacking ensemble model.

This is my code:

```
level0 = list()
level0.append(('log', LogisticRegression()))
level0.append(('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=600, class_weight='balanced')))
level0.append(('xgb', XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight = sum_neg/sum_pos)))
# define meta learner model
level1 = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=10000)
# define the stacking ensemble
model = StackingClassifier(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1, cv=5)

model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel()) 
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

This is the error:

```
764: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.
Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
```

I increased max_iter to 10000 but it still produce this error.

Comment: You need change the `C` hiperparameter (or more or less) to `LinearRegression`, to get a Convergence, or maximixe `tol` hiperparameter

Comment: Can you explain your answer?  Logistic regression can be used as a meta learner model in stacking.

Comment: Your LogisticRegression can't minimize the error until tol (hiperparameter) value, then you can change C value, to remove regulation in your model and try to get any result

Comment: Can you give an example? what is C and tol?

Comment: level1 = LogisticRegression(C=10, tol=0.01, solver='lbfgs', max_iter=10000)